# Flutter: Is it possible to change the mouse cursor for `feedback` widget of `Draggable` widget?

Tags: flutter, widget, mouse, draggable

While dragged widget is dragging I would like to change the cursor to more appropriate `SystemMouseCursor.grabbing` but unfortunately it is not possible to do this by simple Flutter facilities. Maybe someone already had such experience?

Answer (score 2):

After some brain storming I found the enough simple solution. All what need to be done is wrap the `childWhenDragging` widget with `MouseRegion`:

```dart
Draggable(
  feedback: <dragging widget>,
  childWhenDragging: Container(
    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary.withOpacity(0.1),
    child: MouseRegion(
      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.grabbing,
      child: <draggable child>,
    ), 
  ),
)
```